# Alarm not turning on after cancellation via toggleButton

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

My MainActivity's OnCreate method invokes scheduleAlarm method which I implemented in another class called PollReceiver. It has below code in it:

```
    Intent iWeekly = new Intent(context, ScheduledWeeklyService.class);
    PendingIntent piWeekly = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, iWeekly, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgrWeekly = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgrWeekly.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduleTime, Constants.PERIOD_WEEKLY, piWeekly);
```

My app also has a togglebutton to enable or disable the alarms.

The togglebutton code is shown below:

```
    public void enableDisableScheduler(View v){
        if (btnEnableDisableScheduler.isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tb.isChecked()); 
            editor.commit();        

            // Enable all alarms
            PollReceiver.scheduleAlarms(this);

            Log.i(TAG, "alarm is turned on");
        } else {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tb.isChecked()); 
            editor.commit();        

            // Cancel all alarms
            Intent iWeekly = new Intent(context, ScheduledWeeklyService.class);
            PendingIntent piWeekly = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, iWeekly, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmMgrWeekly = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            try {
                alarmMgrWeekly.cancel(piWeekly);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "alarm is not cancelled");
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "alarm is turned off");
        }
    }
```

Now, everything works fine. So, when I exit the app & re-open it again, the above code gets fired again & it re-schedules the alarms which works great as well.

I was trying to avoid this re-scheduling of alarms by putting below code but it does not work. Any idea or help is greatly appreciated. If I turn off the toggle button & turn it on the alarms are not getting scheduled since somehow it doesn't satisfy below condition & does not satisfy below if condition. Any clue or idea how to do this?

```
boolean weeklyAlarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, ScheduledWeeklyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if (!weeklyAlarmUp) {
    Intent iWeekly = new Intent(context, ScheduledWeeklyService.class);
    PendingIntent piWeekly = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, iWeekly, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgrWeekly = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgrWeekly.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduleTime, Constants.PERIOD_WEEKLY, piWeekly);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code to check if the alarm has been scheduled:

```
boolean weeklyAlarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context,
           ScheduledWeeklyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

doesn't work because you are relying on the existing of the `PendingIntent`. When you cancel the alarm you aren't canceling the `PendingIntent` so it still exists, even though the alarm has been canceled.

To fix that, make sure you also cancel the `PendingIntent` when you cancel the alarm, like this:

```
// cancel alarm
alarmMgrWeekly.cancel(piWeekly);
// Cancel PendingIntent
piWeekly.cancel();
```